# Repeat sequence in a listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I would like to enter in a text edit a sequence of type a, b​​, c, d and pass the repeat sequence in a listview repeating 100 times is possible to get this thing

```
a = iter 1 
b = iter 2 
c = iter 3 
d = iter 4 
a = iter 5 
b = iter 6
c = iter 7 
d = iter 8 
a = iter 9 
b = iter 10
c = iter 11 
d = iter 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position%4==1 -> a
position%4==2 -> b
position%4==3 -> c
position%4==0 -> d

where position is the position of getView() function in your adapter

Comment: If I put a, b​​, c, d in an array would get a, b​​, c, d, a, b​​, c, d, a, b​​, c, d, a, b​​, c, d, a, b , c, d 
to each line of the listview should be displayed a in line 1, b in line 2, c in line 3, d in line 4 and so on until you complete 20 lines of listview

Comment: no it can't be in the same line becouse position into adapter is an UID for a line into the listview so use the position from adapter public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {}

Comment: I do not have to enter the names in the same line, each line must match a name, 
maybe you can use a loop